# how can we sign .exe file using .pfx certificate in centos

Tags: exe, centos6, pfx, signtool

I have a exe file which is to be uploaded in Internet .This is to be downloaded by end customer,who has proper accessing privillages. Before that I want to sign it using pfx certificate on Linux (CentOS). I am new to it, but previously I have code-signed my package in mac. But I am new to the Linux. Can any one tell me the procedure to sign it using signtool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with osslsigncode .It worked for me. Install osslsigncode rpm on your linux machine.These links can help in downloading.

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

Before that you should have '.spc' certificate and '.DER' key.

opensssl should help in genrating these above mentioned , if you directly have '.pfx' certificate